# Save the time stamp in "localStorage" and keep these markings

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a point marking application.
works as follows: each click on the button I saved a time stamp,
you can only dial four times (this is already done).
I need to save the four time stamp in "localStorage" and keep these markings without expiring and the other day make and show the new markings below that of the day previous.

```js
function getTime() {
  document.querySelector("button").setAttribute("onclick", "popupAlert()");

  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));
  var data = new Date();
  var full_time = data.getHours() + ":" + data.getMinutes() + ":" +
    data.getSeconds();
  var completeDate = full_time;

  localStorage.setItem('completeDate', completeDate);

  document.getElementById("markTimes").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    '<span class="dataTime" id="dataTimeStl">' + completeDate + ' </span>');
  var qtd = document.getElementsByClassName("dataTime").length;

  if (qtd < 4) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector("button").setAttribute("onclick", "getTime()");
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
    console.log("fim");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getTime()">Marcar</button>
<div id="markTimes"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store an array:

So instead of your line

```
localStorage.setItem('completeDate', completeDate);
```

Do the following:

```
const savedDates = localStorage.getItem('completeDate')

let dates
if (savedDates) {
  dates = JSON.parse(savedDates)

  dates.push(completeDate)
} else {
  dates = [completeDate]
}

localStorage.setItem('completeDate', JSON.stringify(dates))
```

It will add item in array and save it back.
Unfortunately you need to parse, modify and stringify data back for localStorage

Comment: havenchyk, I get the error: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 2 (dates = JSON.parse(savedDates))

Comment: @josecarlos try to clear that key in localstorage, likely there is an old value saved